# BigQuery Security: Impose DDL restrictions on a dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to restrict DDL statements on the tables of a dataset? For example, I want to restrict the ability of the users to add columns to any of the tables of a particular dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [BigQuery Permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bq-permissions), if you take away `bigquery.tables.update` permission from the user. The user shouldn't be able to add a column anymore.

- `bigquery.tables.update`
  Update table metadata.
  To update table data, you need bigquery.tables.updateData.
- `bigquery.tables.updateData`
  Update table data.
  To update table metadata, you need bigquery.tables.update.